# How to prevent file downloading from url if file already downloaded

Tags: java, urlconnection

I need to download files with the possibility to download parts after disconnection. I  have an error when trying to download a file that is already completely downloaded. I get 416 error code from the server when trying to get inputstream. I fixed it by adding a condition downloadedFileSize < urlConnection.getContentLength(). Here my code:

```
try {
                    File file = Path.of(downloadOutputFolder, fileName).toFile();
                    boolean append = false;
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", String.format("bytes=%s-", file.length()));
                        append = true;
                    }
                    if (!file.exists() || file.exists() && file.length() < getFileSizeFromUrl(url)) {
                        try (InputStream downloadStream = connection.getInputStream();
                             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, append)) {
                            int byteRead;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                            while ((byteRead = downloadStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                            }
                        }
                    }...

private int getFileSizeFromUrl(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection.getContentLength();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error during open URL connection to {}", url, e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is it possible to handle these case with url connection api? Not by adding condition `file.length()<getFileSizeFromUrl(url)`.

Comment: shouldn't it say `file.length() < getFileSizeFromUrl(url)` - so it downloads only when the local file is smaller than the remote one ?

Comment: thanks, that is correct. I tested code only when file.length() = getFileSizeFromUrl(url). Updated